# OpenGL ES 2.0 dynamic texture not working

Tags: android, opengl, android-emulator, shader, render-to-texture

I'm very new to Android, Eclipse, and OpenGL ES 2.0 (and object oriented programming in general), but I got a program (basically, based on a few examples I found on the Internet) working to show a cube with each face displaying a different 512 x 512 bitmap image (a PNG image loaded and converted once during the initialization phase) a few days ago.

My system is a 32-bit Vista PC, and I've been using Bluestacks as my emulator (version 0.8.11, released June 22, 2014, Android version 4.0.4). I believe its API level is 15. I have no physical Android devices to test my programs on at this time.

I now want to try a technique to use a dynamic texture.

I've looked for complete Android app examples using a dynamic texture (in Java), but I found only one and when I run it, it doesn't work on my Bluestacks.

Here's the page that has a link to the complete project containing the program:

http://blog.shayanjaved.com/2011/05/13/android-opengl-es-2-0-render-to-texture/

When I run it on my Bluestacks, all I see is a black screen.

One thing I noticed is that the texture size is huge. I changed the size to 512 x 512 (which I know works because my cube program uses 512 x 512 textures), but I still see only a black screen.

(It would be nice if somebody could try to run this program on his/her physical Android device/s and/or Bluestacks and post the result.)

The following is the method in which a dynamic texture is created and prepared for its use:

```
    /**
 * Sets up the framebuffer and renderbuffer to render to texture
 */
private void setupRenderToTexture() {
    fb = new int[1];
    depthRb = new int[1];
    renderTex = new int[1];

    // generate
    GLES20.glGenFramebuffers(1, fb, 0);
    GLES20.glGenRenderbuffers(1, depthRb, 0);
    GLES20.glGenTextures(1, renderTex, 0);

    // generate color texture
    GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, renderTex[0]);

    // parameters
    GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S,
            GLES20.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T,
            GLES20.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,
            GLES20.GL_LINEAR);
    GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,
            GLES20.GL_LINEAR);

    // create it 
    // create an empty intbuffer first?
    int[] buf = new int[texW * texH];
    texBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(buf.length
            * FLOAT_SIZE_BYTES).order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).asIntBuffer();;
    GLES20.glTexImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GLES20.GL_RGB, texW, texH, 0, GLES20.GL_RGB, GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT_5_6_5, texBuffer);

    // create render buffer and bind 16-bit depth buffer
    GLES20.glBindRenderbuffer(GLES20.GL_RENDERBUFFER, depthRb[0]);
    GLES20.glRenderbufferStorage(GLES20.GL_RENDERBUFFER, GLES20.GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT16, texW, texH);

    /*** PART BELOW SHOULD BE DONE IN onDrawFrame ***/

    // bind framebuffer
    /*GLES20.glBindFramebuffer(GLES20.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fb[0]);

    // specify texture as color attachment
    GLES20.glFramebufferTexture2D(GLES20.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GLES20.GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, renderTex[0], 0);

    // attach render buffer as depth buffer
    GLES20.glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GLES20.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GLES20.GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GLES20.GL_RENDERBUFFER, depthRb[0]);

    // check status
    int status = GLES20.glCheckFramebufferStatus(GLES20.GL_FRAMEBUFFER);*/

}
```

Does the above piece of code seem sound?

Oh, one more thing:

I've been using the following as my vertex and fragment shaders. They've been working fine to show a cube with static textures. (Normal's data are read but I'm not using any lights now.)

```
     private final String vertexShaderCode =
        // This matrix member variable provides a hook to manipulate
        // the coordinates of the objects that use this vertex shader
        "uniform mat4 uMVPMatrix;" +
        "attribute vec4 a_Position;" +
        "attribute vec4 a_Color;" +
        "attribute vec3 a_Normal;" +
        "attribute vec2 a_TexCoordinate;" + // Per-vertex texture coordinate information we will pass in.
        "varying vec4 v_Color;" +
        "varying vec2 v_TexCoordinate;" +   // This will be passed into the fragment shader.
        "void main() {" +
        // The matrix must be included as a modifier of gl_Position.
        // Note that the uMVPMatrix factor *must be first* in order
        // for the matrix multiplication product to be correct.
        "  gl_Position = uMVPMatrix * a_Position;" +
        "  v_Color = a_Color;" +
        "  vec3 difuse = a_Normal;" +
        "  v_TexCoordinate = a_TexCoordinate;" +  // pass through
        "}";

private final String fragmentShaderCode =
        "precision mediump float;" +
        "uniform sampler2D u_Texture;" +    // The input texture.
        "varying vec4 v_Color;" +
        "varying vec2 v_TexCoordinate;" +   // Interpolated texture coordinate per fragment.
        "void main() {" +
        "  gl_FragColor = (v_Color * texture2D(u_Texture, v_TexCoordinate));" +
        "}";
```

Should they work when I render to a texture? Or do I have to have separate vertex and fragment shaders when I'm rendering to a texture?

Thank you.